# Volume sound and screen brightness controls not working

Tags: window-manager, i3-wm

Recently I have installed [i3 windows manager](https://i3wm.org/).

The problem is that the footnote keys to control the volume and brightness don't work.

How can I solve this?

And how can I bind the *mod* key to the <kbd>Win</kbd> key?

Comment: if `xbacklight` doesn't work for you, see https://github.com/haikarainen/light

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Multimedia Keys**

First install these packages for brightness and volume:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install xbacklight alsa-utils pulseaudio
```

Then from [I3 FAQ](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3747/enabling-multimedia-keys.1.html):

Add these lines to `~/.config/i3/config`

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle # mute sound

# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

---

**Mod key**

To change the `$mod` key:

- Open `~/.config/i3/config`.
- Look for the line:

  ```
  set $mod
  ```
- Change that to:

  ```
  set $mod Mod4
  ```
- Finally, run `i3-msg reload` to reload the configuration file.

Comment: Works perfectly on Ubuntu 17.04!

Comment: I think it should be slightly modified if you have several sound cards.

Answer (score 3):

For volume, i used the command "amixer",

First, make sure you hava all the devices enabled, to see that first type

```
amixer
```

That should give tou the 'Master' state [on] or [off]

If it is  [off], Set it to [on] by typing

```
amixer sset Master on
```

.

Now changing the default code of:

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 2 +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 2 -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle
```

to this one:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer sset Master 5%+
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer sset Master 5%-
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer sset Master toggle
```

This command increase that percentage to all the output devices

Works perfect for me

Comment: I had to use `bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -D set Master 1+ toggle` for toggling to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

xbacklight doesn't work for me. I wrote this script which writes directly into the kernel exposed back-light files, at least for intel:

https://github.com/jappeace/brightnessctl

I had to do a reinstall recently and just now made a makefile to make installation easier. This is just an alternative for if the xbacklight solution doesn't work for you either.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a variant of the same instructions as always, but for me I found [light by haikarainen](https://haikarainen.github.io/light/) to work best over a variety of hardware:

So in your `i3` config file, set:

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec light -U 10
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec light -A 10
```

Then simply reload with `$mod+Shift+c` or `i3-msg reload` or by directly restarting the WM.

Comment: +1 as xbacklight doesn't work out of the box with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

change set $mod to Mod4 in ~/.config/i3/config

and

add in ~/.config/i3/config:

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle # mute sound

# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

save file

and press $mod+Shift+c or restart i3wm